# Jersey/JAXB marshalling issue with long precision

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

We're using Jersey/Json (v1.12) for a JAX-RS web service and we output longs as part of some simple JAXB object marshalling. We spotted something today and i've had a look around to see if it was a general issue but had no luck debugging.

One of the objects we have uses a long as an unique identifier (according to java specs, 2^63-1 ) which is ~ 9223372036854775807  (19 digits or so).

If we try and output a long (17 or less digits), we get it output as intended (correctly).

If we try and output a long (18 digits up until 2^63-1), we get incorrect output - it seems to round the last 2/3 significant digits e.g.:

```
@GET
@Path("/longTest")
@Produces("application/json")    
public JSONObject testLong() {
    JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        myObject.put("1L", 1);
        myObject.put("13365766603759910L", 13365766603759910L);
        myObject.put("133614582656610538L", 133614582656610538L);
        myObject.put("9133614582656610538L", 9133614582656610538L);    
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myObject;
}
```

returns:

```
{
   "1L":1,
   "13365766603759910L":13365766603759910,
   "133614582656610538L":133614582656610540,
   "9133614582656610538L":9133614582656610000
}
```

Note the wrapping of the last 2 numbers (538 - 540 (18 digits) and 538 - 000 (19 digits)).

If i marshall a long to json directly, it works fine:

```
@GET
@Path("/longTest3")
@Produces("application/json")    
public long testLong3() {
    return 133614582656610538L;
}
```

returns:

```
133614582656610538
```

I've added POJO JSON support on initialisation of my webserver.

Should i be using a different JSONConfiguration or JAXBContextResolver for this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Might be a bug.  You could workaround by reading the value in as a String and using an XmlAdapter to convert it to a Long.  If you annotated a setter instead of the member attribute itself, e.g. setId(Long id), you could extract the primitive type and assign it to a properly-typed member.  None of this will work if you're using these id's for XmlID and XmlIDREFS, however.

Comment: again, a year late. it's 2013, Steve!